# Migration from 0.9.5 to 1.0.1 - ScriptBridge class equivalent

Tags: karate

We would like to move our api test created using karate framework to karate framework 1.0.1. I see that there is no such class as `ScriptBridge` which is used by us to attach screenshots and get information about test status, tags of currently running scenario.
What is the equivalent for the ScriptBridge class?
My question is related with [Attaching screenshots to json report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55345236/attaching-screenshots-to-json-report) where I asked how to attach screenshots to report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer to your question, the class you are looking for is [`ScenarioBridge`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/core/ScenarioBridge.java).

But the HTML reporting has been overhauled and hopefully you will be able to achieve what you need without hacking into internal classes. There is a somewhat undocumented `doc` keyword, you will find an example in the link below. If you feel helpers for handling images need to be part of Karate, do contribute or suggest a feature request.

Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66822585/143475